# How download image with UniversalImageLoader

Tags: android, download, universal-image-loader, androidhttpclient

My app works with UniversalImageLoader.
Now I need to load image from url with UniversalImageLoader.
Why? Because image maybe in cache of UniversalImageLoader.
I don't want to double download image with HttpClient.

I need a simple way to get Image from UniversalImageLoader. How to do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
                .showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.placeholder) // resource or drawable
                .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.placeholder) // resource or drawable
                .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.placeholder) // resource or drawable
                .build();

ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id. ..);

ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(url,imageView,options);
```

**EDITED**:

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().loadImage(url, new ImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {}
                @Override public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {}
                @Override public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {}
                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    //use bitmap from here
                }
            });
```

Comment: I need to download image as bitmap or byte array, not in ImageView.